# Write a SQL query to list all employee names and jobs, whose job title includes M or P?

Tags: mysql

I have to display the names of jobs which contains letters m or p . does'nt matter the position of letters where they are at .they can be either at starting or middle or what ever position.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use like query for this type result-

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE job like ('%m%') OR job like ('%p%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select name,job from employee where jobtitle like '%M%' or '%P%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `LIKE`, we can use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT job
FROM jobs
WHERE job REGEXP 'm|p';
```

### Demo

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  My approach appears to be working from the demo.

Comment: Because he's the hero Stackoverflow deserves, but not the one it needs right now. So we'll upvote him. Because he can take it. Because he's not our hero. He's a silent guardian, a watchful protector. A upvoter knight.

Comment: @Thedude Thanks dude :-) ... I would be curious though to know why this got down voted ^ ^.

Answer (score 0):

TRY This one

```
  SELECT * FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE 'JOBNAME' LIKE '%p%' OR 'JOBNAME' LIKE '%m%'
```